# TFS2013 - Code Analysis configured for build definition, but no analysis result show up in the build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, code-analysis

I'm new to TFS but I've inherited an existing .NET code base with very little development tooling and I'm trying to get a rudimentary CI system up and running. My first task is getting builds configured. I've setup one build to run once a week to do code analysis. If I run analysis locally in Visual Studio everything works fine (and finds a couple thousand issues even with the loosest rule sets). If I configure this build definition to run code analysis 'always', it doesn't seem to do anything. In the build details I don't see any mentions of code analysis or any analysis errors showing up. I'm assuming I'm missing something in the configuration but I can't figure out what. All of Microsoft's documentation I've read indicates that you just update the setting in the build definition settings and that's all that is required.

Also - can anyone point me to any documentation on setting up a pinned report for the TFS dashboard to show the code analysis error count over time?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have installed on your build server?

Comment: You cant pin that data in TFS 2013

Comment: Not even with a custom report? I'll have to go read up on how the dashboard system works, but I'm a little surprised there's no mechanism to display a metric concerning an artifact of the build process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run code analysis, which is a visual studio feature, you need a version of visual studio installed that supports it.

If you install Visual Studio 2013 Premium on your build agent it should start working.

Comment: Ahhhh that's probably it. I have the Visual Studio Shell (Isolated) installed which provides some of the functionality needed to perform builds, but I guess that doesn't cover code analysis? I'll install the full version on my build server and see what happens. Thanks